# all in one printer/scanner and slide scanner

Tags: drivers, printing

I need to be able to print and scan multiple documents and old transparencies (a.k.a. slides). My printer I have now, an Epson xp 310 won't work on Ubuntu. The OS says it has recognized the printer, but when it downloads, it locks up! Same for the slide scanner.

I checked the Ubuntu site, and then cross-referenced this on Amazon to what was available. All I can find is an HP all in one. But I have my doubts that if I spend $300 plus dollars, will that even work?

Lastly, what is CUPS? How does this help to download and install drivers?

Yes, I am new to this Ubuntu, but I am totally sick of today Microsoft dumping software (e.g. Home Publishing, MONEY and others) that I used in my daily life, and then charge an big dollars for rip offs. So now I am dealing with a learning curve I know. But all my research says this is the way to go, and far less costly.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: Rest assured you do not need to spend $300 plus dollars. I think I can help you, but I need more information. For one thing, what version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you provide screenshots of what you are experiencing?  After you have done so, I will show you CUPS.

Comment: Indeed, there is the learning curve at first, but then way cheaper. Long term, that's the best choice. Note that's "Ubuntu" and not "Ubunto". See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(philosophy) (The origin of the OS name...)

Comment: If your question is about how to get the devices you already have to work, we can probably help you with that. However, hardware shopping recommendations are too broad and opinion-based for this site's scope and therefore off topic. You might want to remove that part from your question maybe?

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I think I can help you. The first thing you want to do to set up your printer is to go to the wrench icon found on the left hand side of your computer. This is your settings. Next select the printer, it looks like this:

[image: Printers]

You should see a screen like this: 
[image: Printer_Menu]

Now click on the Add button with the big green + sign next to it. It should be in the top right of the printer menu. Now you should see a screen like this:

[image: Network_Printer_1]

Scroll down to the drop-down arrow next to Network Printer. You should see something like this:

[image: Network_Printer_2]

OK, we are getting there. After you have scrolled down to the printer of your choice, you should see this screen:

[image: Free_Software] Follow the the configuration settings provided in the screenshot, and then click the forward button. After a while the system will ask you for your password:

[image: Password-]

And then it will begin to install.

OK, that's the printer. You also said something about scanning. If your printer has scanning capability, Press CTRL + ALT + T all the the same time. This will open a Terminal window. Now type simple-scan. You should see something like this:

[image: Scanner]

But if it isn't there, just type sudo apt-get install simple-scan.

Go to the Scan button on the top left. It should look something like this:

[image: Scan]

Now, after it is finished scanning, click on the save button. It should look something like this:

[image: Save]

Type in the name you want it to be saved as and you are all set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Kelly-Jeau Larson-did my answer help you?